# AAD pass through authentication - do users need to be provisioned in AAD?

Tags: azure, azure-ad

From their docs - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta-how-it-works

*As a pre-requisite for Pass-through Authentication to work, users need to be provisioned into Azure AD from on-premises Active Directory using Azure AD Connect. Pass-through Authentication does not apply to cloud-only users.*

Doesn't this defeat the whole point of pass-through. If users need to be provisioned in AAD (using AD connect), what's the point of pass through? Or is it just that USERNAMES are provisioned and no passwords..?

Answer (score 0):

Pre-authentication is a mechanism where AAD performs the authentication rather than your server. This is a good thing and yes, it does require your users to be replicated using AAD Connect to Azure AD.

Comment: I'm sorry..your answer is way too basic. The whole idea of pass-through auth is to ensure that identities stay on-prem and never leave your corporate AD. All that leaves your AD is an auth token which is passed around to AAD apps.

 My question is - if you are syncing users across to AAD, why do you even need pass thru authentication? Please only answer if you have actually implemented this.

Comment: Pass-through auth bypasses AAD completely. There is no "AAD token" and no token to pass between services. Pass-through auth is what you'd use when you cannot use KCD or SAML for the target service and/or you did not sync your AD users with AAD.

No one is saying _you_ need pass-through, but it does come in handy for services that do not support KCD/SAML or you want to be protected by the Azure front gate rather than rely on a corporate firewall.